# After setting wifi interface to monitor mode the GUI sets it back to managed mode

Tags: networking, wireless, interface

I used the below commands to set the interface in monitor mode. Everything works, but after a few seconds Ubuntu sets it back to managed mode. How can I disable that?

```
sudo ifconfig wlan1 down 
sudo iwconfig wlan1 mode monitor
sudo ifconfig wlan1 up
sudo iwconfig wlan1 channel 2
sudo iw dev
```